# 8x8 Quantization matrix on 4x4 subsampled matrix. JPEG

Tags: python, algorithm, compression, jpeg

I have a problem with the jpeg algorithm.

We start with a block of 8x8 pixels. Separate luminance Y from crominance Cb and Cr

Then, we subsample Cb and Cr by averaging each 2x2 block.

Thus, Y is 8x8 pixels and Cb and Cr are 4x4 pixels.

Then we apply a DCT

and quantize.

This is what I don't understand. The quantization tables, whether for Y or for Cb,Cr, are 8x8 matrices. **How can Cb and Cr, which are 4x4, be quantized by an 8x8 matrix**?

```
Y_quant = [[0 for i in range(8)] for j in range(8)]
Cb_quant = [[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
Cr_quant = [[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]


quantization_matrix_luminance = [[16,11,10,16,24,40,51,61],
                                [12,12,14,19,26,58,60,55],
                                [14,13,16,24,40,57,69,56],
                                [14,17,22,29,51,87,80,62],
                                [18,22,37,56,68,109,103,77],
                                [24,35,55,64,81,104,113,92],
                                [49,64,78,87,103,121,120,101],
                                [72,92,95,98,112,100,103,99]]

quantization_matrix_crominance = [[17,18,24,47,99,99,99,99],
                                [18,21,26,66,99,99,99,99],
                                [24,26,56,99,99,99,99,99],
                                [47,66,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                                [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                                [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                                [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99],
                                [99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99]]


for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        Y_quant[i][j] = round(Y_dct[i][j] / quantization_matrix_luminance[i][j])
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        Cb_quant[i][j] = round(Cb_dct[i][j] / quantization_matrix_crominance[i][j])
        Cr_quant[i][j] = round(Cr_dct[i][j] / quantization_matrix_crominance[i][j])
```

Comment: For Cb,Cr, you can use a 4x4 matrix, or multiply i.j by 2

Answer (score 0):

In JPEG, the quantization process is applied to the DCT coefficients of the 8x8 blocks of luminance (Y) and chrominance (Cb and Cr) separately. The quantization tables are indeed 8x8 matrices, but they are applied to the DCT coefficients of the 8x8 blocks of Y and the 4x4 blocks of Cb and Cr, respectively.

The reason for this is that the DCT coefficients of the 8x8 block of Y have a higher spatial frequency than those of the 4x4 blocks of Cb and Cr, which have been subsampled by averaging each 2x2 block. Therefore, the quantization table for Y has more values in it than the quantization tables for Cb and Cr, which have fewer values because they represent lower spatial frequencies.

In other words, the quantization tables are designed to take into account the different levels of detail in the different color components. The luminance component contains more detail than the chrominance components, so it requires a larger quantization table to preserve that detail during compression.

Answer (score 0):

4x4 blocks are never processed in conventional JPEG encoding. Everything is optimised throughout for 8x8 DCT coefficient blocks and images are zero padded out to a multiple of 8 (or 16).

Your question assumes JPEG 2x2 chroma subsampling (the default). The smallest block that can be encoded that way is 16x16 (zero padded if needs be). It is possible with JPEG to have no subsampling at all or various other choices. Some commercial applications get this colour subsampling stuff wrong too.

The forwards transform to JPEG coefficients is well defined and amounts to starting with a 16x16 block from the image and averaging 2x2 blocks of Cr & Cb.

Input is always converted into 8x8 blocks so that in a 2x2 chroma subsampled JPEG there are 4 8x8 Y luminance blocks for every Cr & Cb 8x8 block. The quantisation tables are used in full every time. The encoder always encodes an 8x8 image block into JPEG coefficients through a DCT, quantises them using the table and then stores the resulting small numbers Huffman encoded in the output file. Decoding reverses the process with some quantisation error in DCT space.

Whilst the forward transform into JPEG is fully specified how you decode the resulting lower resolution Cr and Cb data and combine it again with luminance Y to make a full colour image is somewhat less well defined. Clipping into valid range and then recolouring is standard practice but a bit approximate.

The normal fast way it is done corrupts the luminance channel somewhat and blurs R&B data across each 2x2 subblock. This means that going round a JPEG encode and decode cycle through a colour image results in more losses than is strictly necessary. Colour bleeding and loss of saturation slowly accumulates. Single saturated R & B pixels on a smooth grey background suffer quite badly.

Some sample images [subsampling red and blue stripes](https://matthews.sites.wfu.edu/misc/jpg_vs_gif/JpgCompTest/subsampling.html)

John Miano's "Compressed Image File Formats" isn't a bad introduction to the topic and covers all the various steps in sufficient detail to be clear.